# Working with Boolean QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I'm having troubles working with a Boolean QuerySet.

models.py:

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', primary_key=True)
     firstConnexion = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

views.py

```
 firstConnexion = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('firstConnexion')

 if firstConnexion:
     Profile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id.id).update(firstConnexion=False)
     return redirect('/one/')
 else:
     return redirect('/two/')
```

The problem is I am only getting the first condition even though `Profile` is updated to `False`

How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `.values()` that you used returns a list of boolean values. In your case, it will return this

```
[False]
```

So, the following will evaluate to True:

```
if [False]
```

as there is something inside the list.

Try the following:

```
if request.user.profile.firstConnexion:
    ...
```

Hope it helps!